# aws sqs to s3 using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Our upstream system is sending JSON messages to our SQS we will have 5 million messages per day.
I need to persist these messages to a S3 bucket for archiving and analytics purpose. I need to dequeue the messages and write 100K messages to a S3 file using lambda function. we will have multiple small files created in S3 buckets to Facilitate quick processing. The lambda would be triggered few times in a day . Any sample code for the lambda function that i can use or any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to 'process' the messages from the Amazon SQS queue _in addition_ to storing the messages in Amazon S3, or is the SQS queue _only_ used for saving the data in S3?

Comment: Are you keeping each day's objects, or are they deleted each day? When you say "we will have multiple small files created in S3 buckets", is each message being stored in its own object, or will the Lambda function combine messages together into a smaller number of messages? I _think_ that the Lambda function will only be given a maximum of 10 messages per invocation.

Comment: Here is our dataflow 
upstream system -> SQS -> Lambda(dequeue & delete message) -> S3(write to file with a limit of 100k rows) -> Cloud datawarehouse(Load from S3) -> Delete processed S3 file(s).
I want to read from SQS - Write to S3 in small batches and delete SQS messages. We will load the S3 files into our cloudwarehouse and all the analytics will happen there.
I need help in writing to S3 buckets from our SQS

Comment: Which 'cloudwarehouse' are you using? Redshift, Snowflake, Databricks? They can all read from 'external tables' stored in S3, but Redshift has an advantage that Kinesis Firehose can load data directly into the database. You seem to be saying that you'd like to convert the "5 million messages per day" into a fewer number of objects in S3, but this depends on the number of messages passed into the Lambda function. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) says "Lambda polls up to 10 messages in your queue at once and sends that batch to your function".

Comment: We are using snowflake. I guess we cannot use Kinesis firehose here since the end point to snowflake is not supported. What is the best way to persist data from SQS to our snowflake database

Comment: The "best" is difficult to say with limited data, but you should consider the native streaming capabilities of Snowflake. See: [Streaming on Snowflake | Snowflake | Medium](https://medium.com/snowflake/streaming-on-snowflake-e94e454ab739) and [Introduction to Snowpipe — Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html)

Answer (score 3):

Processing millions of objects in Amazon S3 is not advisable.

Software or services that attempt to use these objects will be **very slow**. For example, simply listing the contents of an Amazon S3 bucket can only return 1000 objects per API call. Even services such as Amazon Athena that process multiple files in parallel will be very slow in listing and reading that many objects.

An alternative approach would be to send the messages to an [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html), which can combine multiple messages together based on size or elapsed time. It can then store files that combine multiple messages in one, thereby reducing the number of objects created in the S3 bucket.

If you are dealing with 100K+ objects in Amazon S3, also consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.